# How can I query a public facing URL to get my AWS Personalize recommendations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

The [AWS Personalize docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/API_RS_GetPersonalizedRanking.html) state that I can query my campaign and solution like so:

```
POST /personalize-ranking HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json

{
   "campaignArn": "string",
   "context": { 
      "string" : "string" 
   },
   "filterArn": "string",
   "inputList": [ "string" ],
   "userId": "string"
}
```

You will notice that there is no reference to any fully defined endpoint, or how to set one up. Further in the docs, there is only references to making this call using AWS wrappers/SDKs. I cannot use a wrapper for my use case. I need to know how to define an endpoint in a way that I can make this call from a curl command or javascript fetch call, for example. When creating an API gateway, Personalize is not a selectable AWS service.

How do I find/create the URL that I can querying against to get AWS Personalize data?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html I was also searching about what endpoint is, and found this document. hope it helps.

Comment: In general it's bad idea to call it this way. You might run into huge costs due to lack of caching. I would recommend calling GetRecommendations API call from AWS Lambda and hide it behind API Gateway/AppSync and enable caching mechanisms.